# NAT through VPN

Tags: vpn, nat, tunnel

I'm currently trying to access a resource located inside a VPN.

For development purposes I need to use programs I don't have on the laptop that connect to the VPN and - for reasons that still escape me - I haven't been able to duplicate the VPN settings and simply connect from another computer (there's no smart card or other trickery involved).

The issue is that I can't install anything on the laptop with the VPN as I lack admin privileges. The laptop is running Windows 7 32-bit and the other computer is running Windows 64-bit. Is there anything I could use to access the VPN from the 64-bit machine going through the 32-bit one?

Comment: What kind of VPN? What programs are involved?

Comment: The VPN is set up as a VPN network connection in the Windows' Network Connections page. No additional program, as far as I can tell, is involved on the client. As for the server I've got no idea...